# Creating a new buffer with text using EmacsClient

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a program that can send text to any other program for further analysis (eg sed, grep, etc).  I would like it to send the data to Emacs and do analysis there.  How would I do that?  EmacsClient takes a filename by default, this is a data string not a file and I really don't want to create and delete files just to send data to Emacs.

EmacsClient has an "eval" command-line option that let's you execute lisp code instead of open files.  Is there a simple lisp function that will open a new buffer with the given text?

Edit:  I'm looking for something like:

`emacsclientw.exe -eval (open-new-buffer 'hello world')`

And a new buffer would automatically appear with the word "hello world".  I'm not sure how the name of the buffer would be set.  Hopefully something auto-numbered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does what you ask for:

```
emacsclient -e '(open-buffer-with "some\nstuff\nhere")'

(defun open-buffer-with (txt)
  "create a new buffer, insert txt"
  (pop-to-buffer (get-buffer-create (generate-new-buffer-name "something")))
  (insert txt))
```

Obviously you can customize `open-buffer-with` to do what you want.

There's a similar question you might want to look at:  [How do I get basic App<->Emacs integration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699346/how-do-i-get-basic-app-emacs-integration).

Comment: If anybody else is having any trouble with getting this to work in EmacsW32, I had to swap the single-quotes for double-quotes, and escape the double-quotes inside the command: emacsclient -e "(open-buffer-with \"hello, world\")"

Comment: @OtherMichael what you put in works just fine for me in Windows, however I'm running from a cygwin shell.  I don't know how to customize things to work from a general DOS prompt - when I try it from the DOS prompt I get an error "emacsclient.exe: No socket or alternate editor" (of course I started the Emacs from the cygwin shell, which may cause that).

Comment: From the cygwin shell, are you starting EmacsW32, or cygwin emacs?

Comment: @OtherMichael I'm starting the official Emacs (from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/), and not EmacsW32.

Comment: Thanks for pop-to-buffer. Was thrashing trying to write to an existing buffer: no results, no error until calling pop-to-buffer first.

Answer (score 2):

How about this approach?

```
emacsclient -e '
  (progn
    (pop-to-buffer (generate-new-buffer "Piped")) 
    (insert (decode-hex-string "
    '$(perl -e 'print unpack "H*", qq("Hello, World!")'
    )'")))
'
```

I've inserted newlines to break up this very long line for display purposes.

When I run this from a terminal window, a new buffer named `Piped` opens in my Emacs window, containing the text `"Hello, World!"` (complete with quotes).  When I run it again, another buffer named `Piped<2>` opens, with the same text.

The hex-escaping (which can probably be just as easily accomplished with any other high-level language, not just Perl) is for escaping quotes that would otherwise terminate the string constant being fed to `(insert)`.

This approach feeds text to Emacs via Emacsclient on the command line, so very long input text might give it a problem.  A more general solution might be able to break up long input data and feed it to Emacs across several Emacsclient invocations.