# Is it possible to push text from another application into the current buffer of Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I want to make a command-line app that can be used like this:

`$push_to_emacs_buffer "some text"`

Then the current running Emacs will append `some text` into its current active buffer.

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2465518/18636

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
emacsclient -e '(with-current-buffer (window-buffer (selected-window)) (insert "some text"))'
```

On Linux, `push-to-emacs-buffer` can be implemented like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

emacsclient -e "(with-current-buffer (window-buffer (selected-window)) \
                  (insert \"$@\"))"
```

Comment: You have to be a little more careful if your text contains quote marks or other special characters.